# Detect color majority from live camera ? Any idea?

Tags: c#, wpf, camera, detection

I need to make WPF application to detect color majority from live camera ?
any suggestion

how to detect color majority from any image in WPF ?

Comment: How do you define "color majority"? Do you mean the dominant color? Or nuance? You know there are 255^3 colors (not counting the alpha channel), don't you? You could create buckets of colors, i.e. lists of "color ranges", read every pixel and increment the corresponding bucket. Start reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_histogram).

Comment: Yes dominant color ,thank you

Comment: This still leaves place for interpretation. Do you consider that 255.0.0 and, for example, 255.1.1 are the same, i.e. red? You need to define your "color".

Comment: I will need to redefine some colors i need to use , and try to round the color I get to the most nearest one from the predefined color list ? what about that idea ?

Comment: Sounds good. You could define "steps", i.e. the difference between two colors. If this step is `delta`, then, for _red_ for example, you'd have the range `[red - delta / 2, red + delta / 2)`. You could use the euclidian distance for measuring the difference.